# Is it possible to delete files on linux before exporting it like virtual machine?

Tags: centos, networking, virtual-machine, init-script

I know that before exporting a virtual machine you need to shutdown the guest OS. I need to delete a file on the system before exporting the machine or after importing it and starting of loading the network interfaces. To be precise the OS is **CentOS 6.10** and the file is `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

The reason for this is the fact that when importing a virtual machine the MAC addresses are changed and it messes with my interfaces. So I have a script for the automatic creation of interfaces on startup, but I manually remove the file before export. Is it possible to do it automatically or is there a more smart solution for this?

**Update:**

No matter how many interfaces there are when the system boots it is important to have *one* configured interface, the other interfaces are configured from the web interface of the server. Before export I remove the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and on boot, I have a script that takes the first MAC address of the new `70-persistent-net.rules` file and read some IP data from the file and make the config interface. So when the system boots if there is no **SSH** access it will have one up-and-running interface.

Comment: Can you provide the commands you're using or thinking about using to get this done? That would explain the workflow and even your mindset a little better as it relates to this issue.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 updated

Comment: Is this a libvirt, virtualbox, vmware VM?

Comment: It will be used with vmware

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem but is seems that you could just boot the VM, delete the file, shutdown, and export.